# Odoo - Trigger a model method on selecting an item from a One2Many list

Tags: selection, odoo

How can I allow the user to select a single/multiple item(s) from a One2Many list that is embedded in a form? Then how can I trigger some method in the model passing the ID(s) of the selected item(s)?

Please note that api.onchange does not work as clicking on any item row in the One2Many list opens a form.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a boolean field to check the lines of the o2m that you wanna interact with to represent the selected records in the o2m. Your o2m field should be inline editable to be able to check the selected lines. In your main form you could then have a button to call a method that will select the checked records from the o2m field lines in order to get their `ids` and use it for what you really need.

That will do the trick but I think that it's not entirely necessary, you could have for example a wizard to visually select the existing records from the o2m field in order to filter the recordset using a m2m field with search and filter capabilities since you could be working with a large number of records that will make hard to manage the lines selection and also that checked field will somehow be part of the record so you could be affected by concurrency issues where one user select some records and another user select others records in the same form without notice that there are already selected ones leading to undesired behaviors. In the wizard with the selected records you could put your button to process exactly the selected records without the risk of concurrency issues and no need to clean up processed records

Comment: Great answer Axel. Two more things: 1- how can I allow only one selection at a time from the one2many list? 2- How can I automatically trigger a method when this selection changes?

Comment: Also, is there a way to trigger a function directly on user click on a row in the one2many list (ie no checkboxes)?

Comment: You could use a boolean button

Comment: Can you plz elaborate

Comment: Sorry, boolean button is only for form view fields, not for list view fields. You will depending on what you need with that method call, you will need to customize js widgets. Also notice that o2m fields works with in memory data, meaning that the lines may not be saved in the database when you will execute the method

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@api.onchange('your_o2m_field')`

Comment: I tried it but it does not get triggered when the user clicks on an item in the One2Many list. Instead, a form opens with the clicked item data.